# The request operation has failed

Tags: php, apache-2.2

I am installing apache+php on my machine (Ref:http://webdevcodex.com/tutorial-installing-apache2-php5-mysql5-phpmyadmin3-windows-7-vista/) website the same. But after Configuring httpd.conf file apache shows "The request operation has failed" while restarting the server. I am not getting any solution on this from last 3 months.

First time when I have tried it worked file but gave me error for mysql. after that I uninstall apache+php & above problem started.

I am having Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit.

Kindly help

Thanks in advance

Kuldeep

Answer (score 0):

Can You post Ur httpd.conf file here, unfortunately I don't know how to check configuration under Windows, but U can check if httpd.conf is proper with apachectl command.

Comment: ITYM Your and you.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Application Event Log. This should tell you why Apache isn't starting.

It's usually a syntax error in httpd.conf, and the log will tell you what line the error is on.